# Multiple threads in a python script called from the command line

Tags: python, multithreading

On a webserver i am currently implementing in web.py , I am using the following approach to perform an action periodically:

```
import threading    

def periodicAction():
    # do something
    threading.Timer(time_interval, periodicAction).start() # when finished, wait and then start same function in a new thread

periodicAction() # start the method
```

While it works fine (meaning it does what it is supposed to do), I still have the problem, that when I test it from the command line, the console gets unresponsive (i can still type, but it has no affect, even ctrl + c does not stop the program). It this the normal behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background thread is still running, so if the main thread finishes, it will wait -- forever, in this case.  (It's a side-effect of *how* it waits that Ctrl-C doesn't work.)  If you don't want this, you can call `setDaemon(True)`, which makes the thread a "daemon" -- meaning that it will be forcefully closed when the main thread finishes:

```
def periodicAction():
    print "do something"
    t = threading.Timer(1.0, periodicAction)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```